# Ngrx entities with images action/effect pattern

Tags: angular, ngrx

I don't understand how I'm supposed to use ngrx effects and actions when I update or create an object with an image field.

Without an image field the logic is "Component create a new object and dispatch a create request action" -> "An effect listen for that action and call the api, on success it returns a create request action success, pass it the response received from the api" -> "the create request action success related reducer will udpate the store with this new object".

Now if I want to add an image to this logic, I'll need to get the File or Blob object into the effect to add it to the formData sent to the api to make it work.

For example I have a Brand interface defined like that:

```
export interface Brand {
  name: string;
  logo?: string;
```

}

A classical entity store based on this interface with just isLoading and isLoaded booleans.

Actions look like this:

```
export const CreateBrandRequest = createAction(
  '[Brands] Request a brand creation',
  props<{brand: Brand, logo: {blob: Blob, fileName: string}}>(),
);

export const CreateBrandSuccess = createAction(
  '[Brands] Brand creation Success',
  props<Brand>(),
);
```

Where `logo.blob` is a Blob object and `logo.fileName` is the file name. This will allow the `http` service to correctly generate a multipart request that will be accepted by the object. They are only use in the request action, because i don't want to store the Blob or filename in the store, instead I'll store the url of the image received from the backend server.

Reducers:

```
on(BrandsActions.CreateBrandRequest, (state) => ({
  ... state,
  isLoading: true,
  isLoaded: false,
})),
on(BrandsActions.CreateBrandSuccess, (state, brand) => (brandsAdapter.addOne(brand, {
  ... state,
  isLoaded: true,
  isLoading: false,
}))),
```

And an effect that looks like this:

```
createBrand = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(BrandsActions.CreateBrandRequest),
  exhaustMap((action) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', action.brand.name);
    formData.append('logo', action.logo.blob, action.logo.fileName);
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiEndpoint + '/products/brand/', formData).pipe(
      map(response => return BrandsActions.CreateBrandSuccess(reponse)),
      // catcherror logic
      })
    );
  }),
));
```

The problem that I have here is that the parameters sent to the action include a Blob object which isn't serializable. So if I let the strictActionSerializability setting to true, it generates a Detected unserializable action at "logo" error. That's logical, however having to send image on object creation isn't exactly a edge case, rather a very classical scenario, so I suppose that I'm not the first one to encounter this problem. However I can't find any solution that I like. Should I :

- Find a way to serialize the Blob (into a text ? a base64 encoded image ?) and then recreate the Blob in the effect ? That seems to be a lot of workload on the client for nothing and not very elegant.
- Let the setting strictActionSerializability to false ? It seems like I would break one of the key pattern design of ngrx.
- Completely change the logic and use a create service instead of an effect so that I don't have to use an action to send the blob ? I had the impression that the whole create object logic was a perfect use case of an effect.
- Did I miss something completely in the way I'm supposed to use ngrx ?
- Did I miss an easy way to transform the file into something like a base64 encoded image then send it to the backend without having to transform it into a Blob ? I suppose I could store the image as a base64 text field in the backend, however I want the back to store the image as an image and then serve it, without having to modify the back to transform the base64 into an image file (unnecessary use of ressources).

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: why are you returning an image from an API? wouldn't it make more sense to return a URL and have the image served from a CDN or a File server?

Comment: I'm not returning an image FROM an api, I'm sending an image TO an api

Comment: @Jean-XavierRaynaud Hey Jean, have you found a solution to this issue? I am experiencing the same and I'm wondering what the best practice is. Thanks!

Comment: @mosu we end up using websockets intead of http Restful endpoints and reworking the whole application. Somehow it simplified the problem because we have to serialize everything, so we simply used a based64 encoding, parsed on the server side which recreates the image and replace it. With a classical rest api, I'd do the same thing now.